# Mac terminal command to reset wifi without restarting?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

My Macbook (10.14 Mojave) sometimes has trouble connecting to public wifi.  It is hard to be productive when you have 30 minutes and it takes 15 to connect to wifi. Some places it takes a long time for the free wifi sign in page to pop up.

Is there something I can type into terminal that would "reset" the wifi without shutting down? Is there something else I can do to make it connect faster?

Comment: Does turning WiFi off and on through system preferences help?  If so you could replicate this through terminal with `sudo ifconfig en0 down`then `sudo ifconfig en0 up`  See [here](https://alvinalexander.com/source-code/mac-os-x/how-restart-mac-os-x-networking-command-line).

Comment: Some captive portal Wi-Fi networks purposely do annoying things to keep macOS's captive portal detection from working, because they want to be able to read and set cookies on your real web browser, not the sandboxed captive portal window. Try going to http://neverssl.com/ from a browser you don't care about. That usually allows you to deal with the captive portal quickly, without letting it set cookies on your "real" browser.

Comment: Thank you. Wifi seems to be behaving now that I have a solution.  I have a browser with neverssl.com as the homepage and copied the terminal commands so I can try those as well.